# center a div absolutely?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` inside another `div` that has borders on the right and left to center it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dhvfm/

I want to change the inner `div` to `absolute` so that the outer `div` flows up behind it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dhvfm/1/

Now it's not centered. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: You mean vertically, horizontally, or both?

Comment: why you add border for `body` and not `margin: 0 20px;` for `#outer` (without width)? Also, do you want the second example with `position:absolute` to have the same look with the first example?

Comment: yes horizontal, the layout is for reasons that were removed to make the example simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You're absolutely positioning an element but not providing `top`, `bottom`, `left`, or `right`, so it's being left in its original position.  Which would be fine, except…
2. …abolutely-positioned elements with percentage dimensions (`width`, `height`) are a percentage of their *context parent*'s **outer** dimensions (in this case, the `<body>` element).

You can re-center the inner div by [setting `left: 0;` on it](http://jsfiddle.net/Dhvfm/3/), but it will still overlap the body's borders.  To fix that as well, the simplest method is probably to drop the `width` property in favor of [setting both `left` and `right` to the width of the body's borders](http://jsfiddle.net/Dhvfm/5/).  (This acts as a kind of "smart stretching" for absolutely-positioned elements.)

Comment: aha! i had tried that (right and left) but forgot to remove 100% when i did! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is for horizontal centering...

If you know that your inner div is going to be a set height as you have in your example, you can just calculate the margins. For your example: http://jsfiddle.net/Me7HK/2/

As you can see the margin is `(outer height - inner height) / 2`